# SharePoint 2010 audience based on Windows Security Group contains 0 members

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker, security-trimming, audiences

I'm running a SharePoint 2010 environment and have just set up an audience based on a Windows Security Group.

I've set up the following rule:

```
Operand: User
Operator: Member Of
Value: Windows Security Group name
```

When I compile the audience it says the number of members is 0 (zero).

The Windows Security Group in Active Directory has about 7 members already, but they are not shown in the audience.

Does anyone here have experience in setting up SharePoint 2010 audiences based on Windows Security Groups in Active Directory?

Sources used:

- [Microsoft Technet: Plan User Profiles in SharePoint 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721054.aspx)
- [Microsoft Technet: Default User Profile properties in SharePoint 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147513.aspx)

Comment: was there a compilation error when you compiled it? have you specified any audience rules? (if so remove them an re-compile)

Comment: @AnthonyKasses  Thank you for replying.  There are no compilation errors.

Comment: does running the "User Profile Service Application - Audience Compilation Job" manually help?

Comment: @AnthonyKasses - I manually executed the job "User Profile Service - Audience Compilation Job". The job succeeded but it did not populate the audience.  - Do I need to edit the User Profile Service Application Policy setting to include "MemberOf" ?

Comment: no I wouldn't do that and I think it is a reserved property anyway. Maybe ensure the User Profile Service App is healthy and a successful synchronisation has previously been run. Importantly check you're not filtering out these groups/users via the sync. If you do kick off a sync, the compilation job wont start until FIM has finished. (disclaimer here running FULL syncs .. all the usual warnings with FIM apply). Not sure this will help you but audience compilation is based off the UPS app so it pays to check that first.

Comment: Are the user objects directly part of the security group specified or are they nested? I've seen user objects in nested groups not be found by the UPSA it seems to only look one group deep for user objects. Is there any particular custom permission set on the AD group that is preventing the service account that does the sync preventing that group from being found?

Comment: @AnthonyKasses - Do I need to do a Full Synchronisation after creating an audience or adding Windows Security Groups? Where can i check if there are groups or users being filtered out?

Comment: @pigeon - The Active Directory user accounts are directly in the Windows Security Group. In SharePoint I can create an audience, find and select the Windows Security Group. The problem is that there are no members added to the audience. It is not being populated.

Comment: You'll need to do at least an incremental sync after you've created this security group or added user objects to it. If you search for the user accounts in the group can you find them individually in the user profile service database? You can just search for user accounts to see if they appear.

Comment: @pigeon - Lost my login information, so I had to create a new account.
I've run an incremental synchronisation after creating and populating the Windows Security Group. If I do a search, I can find the individual users and Windows Security groups.

Comment: Can I ask what build your farm is at? You could be tripping over a possible bug if its just plain SP1. I'd recommend going to Feb 2012 CUs if thats possible. Either that or theres some kind of unique permission being applied to the group that is preventing the service account that the UPSA uses to compile the audience with those members. Screen shots of your audience rule might help as well.

Comment: @pigeon - ​Build: 14.0.6106.5002 = ​​June 2011 CU Mark 2. When I removed a Synchronisation Connection which only imported AD groups, I got it to work (for about 5 minutes). After changing another setting I broke it again. It might be a bug. PS: for some reason I cannot add comments :( I found the solution here: http://redd.it/vx1gc

Comment: Yeah June 2011 has some User Profile Serivce bugs, you'll want to go to August 2011 or Feb 2012. I build all my farms to Aug 2011 (since i know that works with the 3rd party code that the company I work for writes)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is a very old thread but I just wanted to add one more possible reason which I found.  In my case, I found compiled audiences did not update because the **User Profile Service Application (UPS) Permissions** contained old **Managed Service Accounts** which had been deleted from SharePoint and from AD, but were still registered with full control over the UPS.

I was unable to remove the old accounts from the **UPS Permissions** screen, because they had already been deleted from the **Managed Service Accounts** list, so I ended up having to use PowerShell.  Once I had deleted all the rogue accounts from the UPS Permissions list, I re-ran the user profile sync and then re-compiled the audience, and the membership of the audience updated correctly.